# Why memset function make the virtual memory so large

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory, memset

I have a process will do much lithography calculation, so I used mmap to alloc some memory for memory pool. When process need a large chunk of memory, I used mmap to alloc a chunk, after use it then put it in the memory pool, if the same chunk memory is needed again in the process, get it from the pool directly, not used memory map again.(not alloc all the need memory and put it in the pool at the beginning of the process). Between mmaps function, there are some memory malloc not used mmap, such as malloc() or new().

Now the question is:
If I used memset() to set all the chunk data to ZERO before putting it in the memory pool, the process will use too much virtual memory as following, format is "mmap(size)=virtual address":

> ```
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaab4007000
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaab940c000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaabd80f000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaad6883000
> mmap(67112960)=0x2aaad7084000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaadb085000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaadb886000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaadba89000
> mmap(67112960)=0x2aaadc28a000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaae028b000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaae0c8d000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaae0e8e000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaae108f000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaae1890000
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaae2091000
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaae6494000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaea897000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaeb098000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaaeb899000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaeba9a000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaaeca9c000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaec29b000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaecc9d000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaaed49e000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaafd6a7000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aacc5f8c000
> ```

The mmap last - first = 0x2aacc5f8c000 - 0x2aaab4007000 = 8.28G

But if I don't call memset before put in the memory pool:

> ```
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaab4007000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaab940c000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaad2480000
> mmap(67112960)=0x2aaad2c81000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaad6c82000
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaad6e83000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaadb288000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaadba89000
> mmap(67112960)=0x2aaadc28a000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaae0a8c000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaae0c8d000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaae0e8e000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaae1890000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaae108f000
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaae2091000
> mmap(4198400)=0x2aaae6494000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaea897000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaeb098000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaaeb899000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaeba9a000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaaec29b000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaec49c000
> mmap(8392704)=0x2aaaecc9d000
> mmap(2101248)=0x2aaaed49e000
> ```

The mmap last - first = 0x2aaaed49e000 - 0x2aaab4007000= 916M

So the first process will "out of memory" and killed.

In the process, the mmap memory chunk will not be fully used or not even used although it is alloced, I mean, for example, before calibration, the process mmap  67112960(64M), it will not used(write or read data in this memory region) or just used the first 2M bytes, then put in the memory pool.

I know the mmap just return virtual address, the physical memory used delay alloc, it will be alloced when read or write on these address.

But what made me confused is that, why the virtual address increase so much? I used the centos 5.3, kernel version is 2.6.18, I tried this process both on libhoard and the GLIBC(ptmalloc), both with the same behavior.

Do anyone meet the same issue before, what is the possible root cause?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VMAs (virtual memory areas, AKA memory mappings) do not need to be contiguous. Your first example uses ~256 Mb, the second ~246 Mb.

Common `malloc()` implementations use `mmap()` automatically for large allocations (usually larger than 64Kb), freeing the corresponding chunks with `munmap()`. So you do not need to `mmap()` manually for large allocations, your `malloc()` library will take care of that.

When `mmap()`ing, the kernel returns a COW copy of a special zero page, so it doesn't allocate memory until it's written to. Your zeroing is causing memory to be really allocated, better just return it to the allocator, and request a new memory chunk when you need it.

Conclusion: don't write your own memory management unless the system one has proven inadecuate for your needs, and then use your own memory management only when you have proved it noticeably better for your needs with real life load.

Comment: the process will do thousands of the same allocs, so we use the memory pool, it will save a lot of time, because although the mmap will not do the physical memory allocation, but it really spends too much time for each allocation.